# Fill a disk with an ext4 partition in a script

Tags: linux, partitioning

I tried to use parted for scripted partitionning like so :

```
parted -a optimal /dev/sda mklabel gpt mkpart primary ext4 1 -1
```

But it complains about -1 not being a recognized option. Still the same sub-command works in the parted prompt. So my question is how to use the same options in a script ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Finally found a solution :

```
parted -s -a optimal /dev/sda mklabel gpt -- mkpart primary ext4 1 -1s
```

`--` is very important for it to work here.

Note the use of ‘--’, to prevent the following ‘-1s’ last-sector indicator from being interpreted as an invalid command-line option.

Comment: If the intention is to allocate all remaining space then `-0` will achieve that (instead of `-1` which would leave the last megabyte unallocated).

Comment: I got this error: `The closest location we can manage is 1000kB to 537GB (sectors 1953..1048575966).` replace `1 -1s` with `0% 100%` works

Comment: @ospider No, `0% 100%` is even worse: *You requested a partition from 0,00B to xxxGB (sectors 0..xxxx)*, which means the entire disk — including MBR and partition table itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use --script option. In this case you should put your script part in single quotes.

Example:

```
parted --script /dev/sda 'mkpart primary ext4 1 -1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's parted's argument parser's fault.

Try `parted -a optimal /dev/sda mklabel gpt mkpart primary ext4 1 \-1` or `parted -a optimal /dev/sda mklabel gpt mkpart primary ext4 1 \\-1`

Comment: Thks for your answser. However, `\-1` gives the same error and `\\-1` gives : `Err; "  1" has invalid syntax for locations`